# Number of maximal cliques in a ($2C_4$, $C_5$, $P_5$)-free graph

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

So far, I have found out that chordal graphs have [linear number of maximal cliques](http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/75/531/CS-TR-75-531.pdf) with respect to the number of vertices.
In general case, it is exponential.

I am trying to determine whether the number of maximal cliques in a $(2C_4, C_5,P_5)$-free graph is linear or polynomial with respect to the number of vertices.

In a $(2C_4, C_5,P_5)$-free graph, the largest induced cycle is of length 4, and no two 4-cycles are edge-disjoint.

Is there a paper that mentions such result?

Comment: Also on [cs.se]: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/117238/number-of-maximal-cliques-in-a-2c-4-c-5-p-5-free-graph

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47691/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/117238/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3856299/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was already answered on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/117238/number-of-maximal-cliques-in-a-2c-4-c-5-p-5-free-graph) and on [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47691/number-of-maximal-cliques-in-a-2c-4-c-5-p-5-free-graph).